# document.cookie empty in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cookies, cordova, httponly

I have a phonegap application that communicates with a server using ajax and cookies for session managment.

I need to access the cookies in the client side. I've tried:

```
document.cookie;
```

However, this results in an empty string.

I know that the cookies are set, because the server that the client communicates with can see them.

At first I thought that it is empty because I access document.cookie from a different js file, but even from the same file that makes the ajax request I get an empty string.

Through Chrome's Resources->cookies->localhost I see that the cookies actually exist.

I checked over the server whether the HttpOnly flag is set to true, but it isn't.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I found this plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

However, this results in an empty string as well.

Answer (score 2):

On Phonegap `document.cookie` is empty, since `index.html` and all other files are loaded with `file://` protocol.

You must use [`localStorage`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage).

Comment: Please put some code instead of giving link. It may be expire in future.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the plugin http://plugreg.com/plugin/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin

Git: https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin

Comment: please clarify for what purpose did you read it or tried it ?